# Editing and compiling install_name_tool

Tags: ipa, install-name-tool

I want to add an LC_LOADDYLIB command to my mach o binary file present inside the ipa file. The install_name_tool is used to change any existing library linked to another library. I want to add a new library to the ipa. So i thought if I edit the install_name_tool.c file i will be able to add this functionality. I downloaded the cctools project from Apple open source. The problem is that I am not able to compile the c file. I am getting errors. Can anyone please suggest any solution to link libraries to IPA or compile install_name_tool file.

Answer (score 0):

Install the Xcode command line tools, and you should be able to compile it.

install_name_tool can only do in place editing of library paths in existing LC_LOAD_DYLIB commands. Adding a command requires you to do a lot more...